# Radgridview SumFunction in column footer displays same amount multiple times

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

When the RadGridView is displayed for the first time, the sum in the column footer looks fine.  For example:  $111.22

If a row is added with an amount of $100, the sum adjusts correctly but then it displays this:

$211.22

211.22

If another row is added for $50, the sum displays:

$261.22

261.22

261.22

Likewise if a row is deleted.  The sum repeats itself.

How do I correct this?  Thanks

XAML:

```
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding detailExtendedPrice, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='{}{0:C2}'}" UniqueName="ExtPrice" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Ext. Price" MaxWidth="100" >
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                        <telerik:SumFunction ResultFormatString="{}{0:C2}" />
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I copied some coding from telerik's web site for this aggregate function but discovered that I didn't need it.  This is the code I copied:

```
            Dim f As New SumFunction()
            DirectCast(dgChosenItems.Columns("ExtPrice"), GridViewDataColumn).AggregateFunctions.Add(f)
```

After I commented it out, the sum displays as expected.